# PHP & PDO: Connect to MySQL using IPv6 address

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ipv6

I want to connect to a remote MySQL instance (a Google Cloud SQL one) by using its IPv6 address.

I'm using PHP PDO like that:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=<ipv6-address>;port=3306;dbname=<database-name>',
  '<username>',
  '<password>'
);
```

But it always fails with the following exception message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host

From the terminal I can connect to the MySQL instance, without any issue, like this:

```
mysql --host=<ipv6-address> --user=<username> --<password>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Either you don't have IPv6, or the connection is firewalled.

Comment: If it was the case, I wouldn't be able to connect from the command line.

Comment: @JohannFradj Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @JonasGröger I didn't made any more tests or progress since I've posted this question. From my last understandings, it was a PHP connector issue. Don't forget to share with us if you find something ;-)

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else stumbles over the same problem, and to save them 2 hours delving through PHP source, PDO MySQL IPv6 connections work if you put square brackets around the address.

See: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/streams/xp_socket.c#L568

e.g.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=[1234:5678::42];port=3306;dbname=foo", ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Reading this https://www.saotn.org/php-mysql-and-ipv6-still-slow/ gives the following idea:

> Knowing that, normally, IPv6 takes precedence over IPv4 (which is configurable), users are left with a slow responding website and database operations, only because **connecting to an IPv6 address in PHP is refused**, and the connection refused isn’t handled correctly, making the fallback to IPv4 slow. It takes mysql.connect_timeout seconds

Note: the source does seem credible

Also, this is a good read: http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=798

> Support should be added for MySQL to work over IPv6
>   ("Internet Protocol Version 6").
>   This means:
>   - users can connect with IPv6. **this is partly a connector problem**.
>   - storage of user address information, e.g. in mysql.user, can be in IPv6 format
>   - the proposed new data types CIDR and INET allow IPv6 format as described in WL#2037 "Add CIDR and INET data types"
>   - functions like inet_ntoa() need revision

Comment: That would be weird. Also there is other PHP's components that seem to support ipv6 like sockets http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php

Comment: apparently the issue is localized in the php mysql connector... sorry about the bad news.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this for your PDO conenction and see if it works.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=<ipv6-address>;port=<port>;dbname=<dbname>', <dbusername>, <dbpassword>);
```

In case if fails, you can better use `try...catch` to get exactly at the error

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=<ipv6-address>;port=<port>;dbname=<dbname>', <dbusername>, <dbpassword>);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any difference between your code and mine? And I've already pasted the exception error message. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried connecting without the `port` in your code in case a different port was configured to listen to database connection?

Comment: Try connecting using native `mysql` and see what happens. If it connects then you should test to know if your server supports or has the `PDO extension` installed.