# PHP: Connect to MSSQL database with IPv6

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, ipv6

Using PHP (with the dblib driver), I am trying to connect to a MSSQL server with an IPv6 address. The code looks something like this:

```
<?php

$db_host = 'ff3e:30:fd66:98:5837::';
$db_port = '1433';
$db_name = 'thedb';
$db_user = 'theuser';
$db_pass = 'thepass';

$conn = new PDO("dblib:host=$db_host:$db_port;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$conn = null;
```

Running this with `php check.php` returns `[ERR] SQLSTATE[HY000] Unknown host machine name (severity 2)`, even though the host and the port are 100% correct and there is no firewall issue, since I can easily `nmap` it:

```
$ nmap -6 -Pn -p 1433 ff3e:30:fd66:98:5837::
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-02-05 16:50 CET
Nmap scan report for <hostname> (ff3e:30:fd66:98:5837::)
Host is up (0.0019s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1433/tcp open  ms-sql-s
```

**Why doesen't this work? Is it an IPv6 issue?**

---

If its helpful, executing `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()` results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => dblib
    [1] => mysql
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP & PDO: Connect to mysql using ipv6 address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398160/php-pdo-connect-to-mysql-using-ipv6-address)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Note that we are talking about M**S**SQL here.

Comment: It doesn't matter because we're talking about a PDO connection. PDO is database agnostic.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Agreed. However, the duplicate you linked is specifically about MySQL being slow. I don't understand how that could be linked here.

Comment: Because the error in the narrative is exactly the same and doesn't mention speed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Which means its related, not duplicate.

Comment: No, it is a duplicate question and the answer is pretty clear *"connecting to an IPv6 address in PHP is refused"*. I promise, I am not trying to be difficult.

Comment: The IPv6 address is a multicast address. Is that really the address you're supposed to connect to?

Comment: @SanderSteffann I just obfuscated the real one and I guess chose a multicast one by chance.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Does that mean that from within PHP, you cannot access IPv6 *in general*? If yes: wow! Thats rediculous... I can't find any information about this issue online...