# Connect to Wordpress database with ipv6 host

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to connect with MySQL using an ipv6 host but it's not working. I have encountered the following errors with my attempts:

Attempt #1:

`define( 'DB_HOST', 'fe80::ec4:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX' );`

2017/06/30 08:55:48 [error] 11954#11954: *4827 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): **php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in***...

PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in...

---

Attempt #2:

Following [PHP & PDO: Connect to MySQL using IPv6 address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398160/php-pdo-connect-to-mysql-using-ipv6-address)

`define( 'DB_HOST', '[fe80::ec4:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX]' );`

2017/06/30 06:57:35 [error] 11954#11954: *4647 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): **Failed to parse IPv6 address "[fe80:3306"**

I have no idea why the log file says `&quot;[fe80:3306&quot;` when my address starts with `'fe80::ec4`.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Do you have a localhost MySQL server? If so, does `define( 'DB_HOST', '[::1]' );` work? `::1` is the IPV6 way of saying `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. This is what I got: `PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Failed to parse IPv6 address &quot;[:3306&quot; in`

Comment: Are you sure your host, the one running php, has IPV6 enabled? Can you connect from that host using ssh or something to the MySQL host using IPV6 addressing? What version of php is on your host?

Comment: I can connect successfully with this command: `mysql -u <user> -p -h fe80::ec4:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%eth0 <db>`. I did try appending `%eth0` to `DB_HOST` but I get the same errors as above. I'm running php7.0 on centos 7.3.

Comment: Same here and I also tested using the SQL CLI